# Load a class dynamically

Tags: python, python-import

I have a software that dynamically adds modules at startup.
The start happens after the start of my Python program, so I cannot import the modules with a normal "import DynModule", but have to do this during runtime.

Therefore I would like to do something like this:

```
def load_module():
    try:
        import site
        site.addsitedir(r"C:\Users\...")
        from DynModule import Foo
        
     except (ModuleNotFoundError, ImportError) as e:
        logger.error("Could not import the dynamic module")
        
        class AccessClass(Process):
            def __init__(self):
                Process.__init__(self)
                logger.info("Placeholder class instance")
            
            def do_something(self):
                logger.info("Placeholder does something")
                
    else:
        class AccessClass(Process):
            def __init__(self):
                Process.__init__(self)
                logger.info("The right class instance to use the dynamically loaded module")
            
            def do_something(self):
                logger.info("Actually does something")
```

And then do something like this in the main program:

```
def action_on_load(self):
    from loader import load_module, AccessClass
    
    load_module()
    self._access = AccessClass()
    self._access.do_something() # prints "Actually does something"
```

However, I cannot import AccessClass as it is defined inside the try-except clause.

How can I proceed and get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that its defined in the `try` statement, but that it's defined in the *function*, where the name `AccessClass` is a local variable. You can declare the name as global:

```
def load_module():
    global AccessClass
    ...
```

because a `class` statement is like a fancy assignment statement: it defines  a class, then binds it to a name. Note, though, that the class won't be assigned to the name until you actually *call* the function. In your main program, you'd need to write something like

```
def action_on_load(self):
    import loader  # No AccessClass yet
    
    loader.load_module()  # Now loader.AccessClass is defined.
    self._access = loader.AccessClass()
    self._access.do_something() # prints "Actually does something"
```

Or, you can simply *return* the class:

```
def load_module():
    ...

    return AccessClass


def action_on_load(self):
    from loader import load_module
    
    AccessClass = load_module()
    self._access = AccessClass()
    self._access.do_something() # prints "Actually does something"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The AccessClass inherits from multiprocessing and I have problems when I try to start the process. This is obviously because Pickle cannot serialise local (inner) functions. Do you see a way around this?